# wordpress gravity forms submit multiple times

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using Gravity Forms with easy modal to allow the user to build an email distribution list for blog posts.

I have it all wired up and working perfectly aside from the fact that I can't figure out how to completely disable the confirmation page after the form is submitted.

The effect that I am looking for is that the user can enter an email address, submit the form (via ajax), and then have the form redraw so that a 2nd, 3rd, etc.. email address can be entered. Right now I have to completely reload the page to get the form out of the "submitted" state.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a plugin which allows you to reload any AJAX-enabled Gravity form.

http://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gp-reload-form/

In the demo, you click a link to reload the form; however, it also provides an option to automatically reload the form after X seconds. Additionally, you can trigger the reload manually (like when the popup containing the form is closed) anywhere in your javascript like so:

```
gwrf.reloadForm();
```

This plugin works by saving a copy of the form HTML when the form is loaded and then when called to reload the form, it replaces the confirmation markup with the save HTML markup.

Comment: and you will have to pay for this plugin